# Proof that sequential GARCH fitting is not efficient?

Tags: arima, garch, fitting, efficiency

I've read that authors like Tsay (as well as several other researchers) use a sequential method for fitting a ARCH-type model. This means first estimating the conditional mean model (ARMA-type) and then using that as a mean model for the ARCH.

At the same time, I've read that this method might lead to estimations not being efficient.

Does anyone have a (mathematical) proof (or knows where to get it) of this?

Comment: Simple: an ARMA model will not be fit efficiently if its assumptions are not satisfied; presence of GARCH violates the assumptions. The residuals from ARMA will not correspond to efficient estimates of the true underlying errors, hence also the GARCH model will be fit on poorly measured errors, which makes the GARCH estimation inefficient, too.